# async / await in node / express does not seem to wait for Promise to resolve

Tags: node.js, express, promise, async-await

I have a simple script outside of express to test this, and my script works as expected. However, the following code does not seem to meet my expectations.

**code**

```
async function getTest(type, key) {
  var body = await tloader.pload(type, key)
  console.log(body)
  return body
}

router.get('/pages/test', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Running test...")
  var content = getTest('tplt', 'primary')
  console.log(content)
  res.send(content)
  console.log(content)
})
```

The console logs:

```
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello World - I love you all! It works!</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Promise is only resolved after sending the content (which is also sent as {  } `object`

For what it's worth, the code containing the promise is:

```
var pload = function(type, tname) {
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        var key = keybase + type + ":" + tname
        rcli.get(key, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(res)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

( And, yes, I know I don't have a try catch to handle a promise rejection. )

Comment: `getTest()` returns a promise.  You are calling it, but not using either `.then()` or `await` to wait for the promise to finish.  Therefore, you call `res.send()` BEFORE `getTest()` has finished.  You need to use either `await getTest()` or `getTest().then()` to actually wait for the promise to resolve.  If you use `await getTest()`, then you have to declare the containing function as `async`.

Comment: I think I get it now. It's kind of weird that 'await' has to be in an async function, when the effect is to create synchronous behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Your `async` function is essentially a "Promise".

```
router.get('/pages/test', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Running test...")
  getTest('tplt', 'primary').then(content => {
    console.log(content)
    res.send(content)
    console.log(content)
  });
})
```

Alternatively you *may* be able to use async/await in the express callback, I'm not sure how express will handle that.

```
router.get('/pages/test', async function(req, res) {
  console.log("Running test...")
  const content = await getTest('tplt', 'primary');
  console.log(content)
  res.send(content)
  console.log(content)
})
```

Comment: Ok, That works... thank you. But: I don't understand why it works there, and not in my getTest function? That also uses await to wait for the Promise to resolve within the function, and the console logs an unresolved promise.

I'm worried this is an ephemeral or accidental fix...

Comment: `async` functions work fine in express, the only requirement is that if you don't accept the `next()` argument, you must handle the response, but that's required for normal functions too.

Answer (score 0):

```
async function getTest(type, key) {
  var body = await tloader.pload(type, key)
  return body
}

router.get('/pages/test', async function(req, res) {
  console.log("Running test...")
  var content = await getTest('tplt', 'primary')
  console.log(content)
  res.send(content)
  console.log(content)
})
```

As we know if we convert any normal function as an async function then it will return as a Promise, for that every promise has to be resolved by (then function) or (await keyword). When your router function sees no promise resolver keyword it will back out of the stack immediately so if you want your router function to await until promise resolve you have to make your router function async and then await getTest to get the value.